# Windows: How to create a shortcut for the Safely Remove Hardware dialog?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I find it useful to have a handy shortcut icon for the hardware removal operation. How do I create a shortcut for the Safely Remove Hardware dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
```

Source: [Create a Shortcut or Hotkey for the Safely Remove Hardware Dialog](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-for-the-safely-remove-hardware-dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond `chopeen`'s answer, if you find your USB device does not accept a remove operation.

Read these [tips for pendrives](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbstick_e.html).
You might also want to keep the [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html#RemoveDrive) tool handy.